# How to handle image on disable UIButton

Tags: ios, image, uibutton

I have an image 128 x 128 px. Setting on a custom button size 42 x 42.

Issue: I am placing that image on button. When that button in enabled state, image looks good : 
[image]

But when button is in disabled state, image quality is distorted, like this
[image]

I am not sure how to deal with this problem. Any pointers on this is very much appreciated.

One more info. this is for retina display.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried scaling the image to 84x84?

Comment: No, I am not scaling the image. Do I need to scale it to 2x? Why I am asking this because, its working perfect when button is enable.

Comment: No, I'm saying you **should** try scaling the image to 84x84. Unless **you're** saying that you don't **want** to scale the image. In which case, why not?

Comment: OMG .. it worked. Thank you very much. But I am still thinking, how a image larger than 2x is not working when button is disable and working when its enable.

Comment: Cool, posting as an answer. I agree that it's a bit counterintuitive, but scaling can distort images, and so can the kind of modification that is done to gray out an image. So it's not a huge stretch to imagine that the combination might do something that one or the other might not.

Answer (score 1):

I would try resizing the image to the right size: i.e., 84x84 for the retina version and 42x42 for the regular version.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a Boolean and set it to true or false whenever the button is pressed. And then change the image in accordance to the Boolean state.